# Amazon S3 Unicode filenames, which Unicode Normal form?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, amazon-s3

I've recently discovered that Amazon S3 will by default make files with Unicode in their names available through URLs that are percent-encoded in UTF-8 in a **Decomposed** Unicode normal form.

I'm however not sure if it's NFD or NFKD, and I suspect that I might accidentally pick the wrong one and get away with it for a while, until something breaks when an odd character shows up somewhere. Couldn't find this documented anywhere on Amazon.

Has anybody figured this out in the past?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well you could test it by using `⁵` in a filename, if you see `%E2%81%B5` it's NFD, if you see `5` it's NFKD

Comment: It's the former! I didn't know of a test character to verify that with, so ⁵ was extremely helpful, thank you! Do you mind writing up a response for my question so that I can mark it as solved / upvote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could test it by using `⁵` in a filename, if you see `%E2%81%B5` it's `NFD`, if you see `5` it's `NFKD`

See [compatibility composite figure](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Compatibility_Composite_Figure)